# R k-means producing "computationally singular" error

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a dataset with 29 observations and 15 variables. I am trying to perform k-means cluster analysis and when I try to determine the number of clusters using NbClust package, I get the following error:

```
> library(NbClust)
> set.seed(1234)
> nc <- NbClust(df, min.nc=2, max.nc=15, method="kmeans")
Error in solve.default(W) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.50527e-17
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In pf(beale, pp, df2) : NaNs produced
2: In pf(beale, pp, df2) : NaNs produced
```

If I remove one variable which increases my observations to 41 (i.e., data frame is 41 x 14 now), NbClust does work.

Can someone help me understand why I am getting computationally singular error with 29 x 15 data frame?

Also, even with the 41 x 14 data frame, I do not see a clear bend in wss plot:

[image: wss plot]

NbClust suggests 15 clusters. Does this mean I do not have clear clusters?

Comment: Is it possible that some of your columns are identical ?

Comment: There are no identical columns although a few rows share same values in 3 columns (e.g., row 1 (5, 8, 10), row 2 (5, 8, 10)).

Comment: Identical rows will also lead to a singular matrix. Or rows/columns that are linear combinations of other rows/columns.

Comment: Hm, but why is that when I have 41 x 14 data frame that still contains identical rows, it seems to be working?

Comment: I'd hazard that this is more of a statistical/dimensionality problem than a programming issue. Probably better suited for stats.stackexchange than here as it seems to be about the applicability of k-means to extremely sparse data.

Answer (score 0):

The WSS plot suggest that it **did not work at all**.

A plot like this indicates that there is probably only *1* cluster.

Maybe due to inadequate preprocessing, or because the algorithm is a bad choice *for this data*. Either way, I'd assume the result to not work.